# Query error: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting an error when tries to execute the following query:

```
select r.* 
from dataset.table1 r
where id NOT IN (select id from staging_data.table1);
```

It's basically a query to load incremental data on a table. The dataset.table1 has 360k rows and the incremental on staging_data has 40k. But when I try to run this on my script to load on another table, I got the error:

```
Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory
```

This started to happen on the last week, before that it was working well.

I looked over for solutions on internet, but all the solutions doesn't work on my case.

Has anyone know how to solve it?

---

I changed the cronjob time and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I'm surprised that you would get this error for this shape of query. Do you have a sample job ID? Are you using standard SQL or are you using legacy SQL?

Comment: Hi Elliot, sorry for the late response, but when I changed the cronjob hour it started to work, two days in a row without the problem. I'm using standard sql, btw. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can try using writing the results to another table, as Big Query has a limitation for the maximum response size that can be processed. You can do that either if you are using Legacy or Standard SQL, and you can follow the steps to do it [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#large-results).

Comment: Hi @Yandrak3, when I changed the cronjob hour, the problem seems to be fixed. Thank you!

Comment: I know this isa bit old, but does `OVER (PARTITION BY ...` has the same effect?